# Efficiently Reshape 3D Numpy Array into 1D List Plus Coordinate Vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I've got a large nested array `a` (256x256x256) that I need to restructure into a list with elements like this:

```
[ (i,j,k), a[i,j,k] ]
```

I'm currently doing this as follows:

```
aflat = a.flatten().tolist()
coords = list(itertools.product(range(256), repeat=3))
thelist = [list(x) for x in zip(coords, aflat)]
```

This works, but it's rather slow.

I can probably save a second or so by removing the runtime generation of the coordinate vectors and reading those from a file instead. However, the main slowdown seems to be in the last line, which is clocking in at over 6 seconds.

Is there a faster way to generate the data structure I need in Python?

Comment: It looks as though the problem is the dynamic allocation. You're creating 2^(8*3) lists. Your initial choice of datatype looks questionable. Surely you want something fixed size that you can preallocate... hunt for 'struct pack'

Comment: [```numpy.ndenumerate```](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate) May be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @P-i commented, the major problem is that the code creates a ton of lists, and Python spends a lot of time doing memory management.  To eliminate this, you can use numpy arrays to preallocate the data, and use its `repeat` and `tile` functions to generate the `i,j,k` values:

```
# order='F' is important here so column-wise assignment can
# occur with a stride of 1.  Switching the order results
# in a significant performance hit.
coords = numpy.zeros([a.size,4],'d',order='F')

NI, NJ, NK = a.shape

# build columns for (i,j,k) tuples using repeat and tile
coords[:,0] = numpy.repeat(range(NI),NJ*NK)
coords[:,1] = numpy.tile(numpy.repeat(range(NJ),NK), NI)
coords[:,2] = numpy.tile(range(NK), NI*NJ)
coords[:,3] = a.flatten()
```

This results in an array where each row is `(i,j,k,value)`.  It does assume that your original array is in [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)  ordering (C-ordered arrays in numpy).

In my timings, based on ten iterations in Python 3.5 on a 2013 MacBook Pro, it took about 20 seconds per transformation to run the OP's transformation and only about 8 seconds per transformation using this method.

The output format really has to be a list, the array can be converted into a list in the final step.  However, this increased the transformation time to 13 seconds per transformation in my testing.

Comment: Interesting idea, but is this really faster? I may be doing it wrong, but trying some simple benchmarking in ipython, this method is taking about 30% more time than what I posted.

Comment: @MarcoTompitak My timing results agreed with yours.  After a bit of investigation, I think the major performance hit is memory management, as indicated by one of the commenters.  I put a bit more thought into the problem, and found that you can save a significant amount of time if you keep the output in an array format.

Comment: Amazing! I don't know where the difference in our timings come from, but on my computer your method is 8-9x faster, not just a factor of 2. I reworked the rest of my code to deal with arrays for as long as possible (I needed to convert to a list at some point) and it runs much faster. The bottleneck has shifted from the generation of the data structures to the actual analysis I'm doing, which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @wii's comment above, you're looking for `np.ndenumerate`.

Typically, you'd avoid explicitly creating your list and use an iterator instead.  For example:

```
for (i,j,k), val in np.ndenumerate(your_3d_array):
    assert val == your_3d_array[i,j,k]

# Note that we also could have done:
for ind, val in np.ndenumerate(your_3d_array):
    assert val == your_3d_array[ind]
```

However, if you did want to create the full intermediate list, you'd use:

```
list(np.ndenumerate(your_3d_array))
```

As a more complete example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3, 4, 5)

In [3]: x
Out[7]:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])

In  [4]: list(np.ndenumerate(x))
Out [4]: 
[((0, 0, 0), 0),
 ((0, 0, 1), 1),
 ((0, 0, 2), 2),
 ((0, 0, 3), 3),
...
 ((2, 3, 1), 56),
 ((2, 3, 2), 57),
 ((2, 3, 3), 58),
 ((2, 3, 4), 59)]
```

Comment: This is most definitely a lot simpler, but it doesn't seem to be faster. Trying it out on a 256x256x256 array, this is over 20% slower than my code on my end. It also gives a list of tuples, rather than a list of lists. It's the conversion to lists in my code that is causing a big slow-down. If I simply leave that out and only use `zip()` (so I get a list of tuples) I already get reasonable performance (over 2.5x faster than `ndenumerate()`.) Is it different on your end?